# Using KILL with a declared variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to use a KILL statement with a declared variable but it's giving me a syntax error. Is there anyway to not use a constant and programatically change the SPID?

For example:

```
DECLARE @SPID smallint
SET @SPID = 100
Kill @SPID
```

BTW this is just an example. I need to run the kill in a loop with a cursor to get rid of old persistant user connections. (Don't ask)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think you're going to need dynamic SQL for this.  Read [this essential page](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) before doing anything with dynamic SQL, please.

```
DECLARE @SPID smallint
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(1000)

SET @SPID = 100

SET @SQL = 'KILL ' + CAST(@SPID as varchar(4))

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always do this via SMO as well, using powershell or C# :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.killprocess(v=sql.110).aspx

This kind of management of sql server and the code that goes with it is just what powershell and SMO are good at, and T-SQL can sometimes be fiddly with.

Comment: That a long way to go for a really short ride

Comment: Yes, for this example, but you can do so much with SMO once you get the hang of it. Learning how to use it (and powershell) opens up a whole raft of opportunities for streamlining and automating management of SQL server.