# How to kill session using tsql

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, casting

Hello I have problem with cast issue . Even the results come from query as string i get Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near '@session_id'.
then I tried to use cast method but it did not worked .

```
declare @counter        int;
declare @session_id     int;

set @counter=0;
select 
    @counter= count(*),
    @session_id=cast(req.session_id as int) from sys.dm_exec_requests req where req.command='DbccSpaceReclaim'group by req.session_id
if(@counter>0)
begin
kill  @session_id 
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15010689/using-kill-with-a-declared-variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following, I am using sp_executesql. For more information see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

```
declare @counter        int;
declare @session_id     int;

set @counter=0;
select 
    @counter= count(*),
    @session_id=cast(req.session_id as int) from sys.dm_exec_requests req where req.command='DbccSpaceReclaim'group by req.session_id
if(@counter>0)
begin

declare @sql nvarchar(1000)
select @sql = 'kill ' +  cast(@session_id  as varchar(50))
 exec sp_executesql  @sql
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it does not work (SQL Server 2008 R2)

```
DECLARE @sSQL varchar(MAX)
SET @sSQL = 'KILL 58'
EXEC sp_executesql @sSQL
```

It does not kill the session

---

```
KILL 58
```

This works

---

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a variable as a parameter to the `kill` command directly.

Try creating a small piece of dynamic SQL and then executing it, as follows:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(50)

IF(@counter>0)
BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'kill ' + CAST(@session_id AS NVARCHAR)
    EXEC @sql
END
```

This achieves the same result as you desire by executing the `kill` command with the value of `@session_id`.